# Cannot assign "'Nokia1200'": "Order.pname" must be a "Product" instance

Tags: django

I have a 'Product' Model in which all the details of a product is available and I have a 'Order' Model with Foreign Key of Product Model. I am filtering the details on a particular field and trying to add that field in Order Model.
I applied this concept on a particular field like this: Product.objects.filter(pname='Nokia1200').values('pname','catgry','brand').
But it's produced an error message.

## Form.html

```
                   <form class="well form-horizontal" method="post" action="{% url 'new_order' %}">
                {% csrf_token %}
                  <fieldset>
                     {% for n in ListPrdt %}
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Select Product</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6 inputGroupContainer">
                           <div class="input-group">
                              <span class="input-group-addon" style="max-width: 100%;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i></span>
                              <select class="selectpicker form-control" name="pname">                          
                                <option>{{n.pname}}</option>                                     
                              </select>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Category Name</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6 inputGroupContainer">
                           <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                            <input id="fullName" name="catgry" placeholder="Full Name" class="form-control" required="true" value="{{n.catgry}}" type="text">
                          </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>

                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Brand Name</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6 inputGroupContainer">
                           <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                            <input id="fullName" name="brand" placeholder="Full Name" class="form-control" required="true" value="{{n.brand}}" type="text">
                          </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     {% endfor %}
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Quantity</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6 inputGroupContainer">
                           <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span><input id="email" name="qnty" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" required="true" value="" type="text"></div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Price</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6 inputGroupContainer">
                           <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></i></span><input id="phoneNumber" name="price" placeholder="Phone Number" class="form-control" required="true" value="" type="text"></div>
                        </div>
                     </div>

                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Tax</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6 inputGroupContainer">
                           <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span><input id="addressLine2" name="tax" placeholder="Address Line 2" class="form-control" required="true" value="" type="text"></div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Total</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6 inputGroupContainer">
                           <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span><input id="city" name="total" placeholder="City" class="form-control" required="true" value="" type="text"></div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Delivery Date</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6 inputGroupContainer">
                           <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span><input id="state" name="deliverydt" placeholder="State/Province/Region" class="form-control" required="true" value="" type="text"></div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Remarks</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6 inputGroupContainer">
                           <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span><input id="postcode" name="remark" placeholder="Postal Code/ZIP" class="form-control" required="true" value="" type="text"></div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Select Brand</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6 inputGroupContainer">
                           <div class="input-group">
                              <span class="input-group-addon" style="max-width: 100%;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i></span>
                              <select class="selectpicker form-control" name="conrej" disabled>

                                 <option>Confirm</option>
                                 <option>Rejected</option>

                              </select>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                    <button>Submit</button>

                  </fieldset>
               </form>
```

## Model.py

```
class Order(models.Model):
Reject = 'RJ'
Confirm = 'CN'
confchoice = ((Reject, 'Reject'),(Confirm, 'Confirm'),)
pname = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
catgry = models.CharField(max_length=10)
brand = models.CharField(max_length=50)
qnty = models.CharField(max_length=10)
price = models.CharField(max_length=20)
tax = models.CharField(max_length=20)
total = models.CharField(max_length=20)
deliverydt = models.CharField(max_length=20)
remark = models.CharField(max_length=10)
conrej = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=confchoice,  default="Reject")

def __str__(self):
    return self.remark
```

## Views.py

```
def NewOrder(request):
add_prdt = Product.objects.filter(pname='Nokia1200').values('pname','catgry','brand')
return render(request, 'neworder.html', {'ListPrdt' : add_prdt})
```

## Product Model

```
class Product(models.Model):
pname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
catgry = models.CharField(max_length=20)
brand = models.CharField(max_length=20)
price = models.CharField(max_length=10)
qnty = models.CharField(max_length=10)
vname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
mfd = models.CharField(max_length=20)
exp = models.CharField(max_length=10)
height = models.CharField(max_length=10)
width = models.CharField(max_length=10)
color = models.CharField(max_length=10)
wght = models.CharField(max_length=10)
remark = models.CharField(max_length=50)
hsn = models.CharField(max_length=10)

def __str__(self):
    return self.pname
```

## Views.py File(For add new order in Order Model)

```
def new_order(request):
pname = request.POST.get("pname", False)
catgry = request.POST.get("catgry", False)
brand = request.POST.get("brand", False)
qnty = request.POST.get("qnty", False)
price = request.POST.get("price", False)
tax = request.POST.get("tax", False)
total = request.POST.get("total", False)
deliverydt = request.POST.get("deliverydt", False)
remark = request.POST.get("remark", False)
OrderNew = Order(pname = pname, catgry = catgry, brand = brand, qnty = qnty, price = price, tax = tax, 
                total = total, deliverydt = deliverydt, remark = remark)
OrderNew.save()

return render(request,'neworder.html')
```

Comment: where is your add code? where you are saving the order model with model

Comment: Please show the full traceback

Comment: Where is your Product model?

Comment: I included the add code of Order Model @Exprator

Comment: what is getting passed to pname while taking input from form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your filter query is:

```
product=Product.objects.filter(name='Nokia1200').first()

Order.objects.create(pname=product,.......)
```

Comment: It's gives an error like this : The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing

Comment: I have edited..sorry for the error @AbhishekKumar..Please upvote and accept answer if it works

Comment: Now it gives an error: 'Order' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: try "only"  instead of values @AbhishekKumar

Comment: Tell me one thing @Mohit Harshan that the 2nd query you have written where you Order table but I'm filtering from the Product Table so is it correct or not.

Comment: Please show me your product table!Include it in your question

Comment: Now  wat is your error?? IS NewOrder function still there or you created new_order instead?

Comment: Both functions are there. NewOrder is used for page reference and new_order is used for storing the data.

Comment: And the error is same that is the heading of this questions @Mohit Harshan

Comment: pname in order is a foreign key to product model..SO would there be multiple products returned with pname with 'nokia2100'?

Comment: But there is only one pname is available with 'Nokia1200' @Mohit Harshan

Comment: Tell me one thing that if I assign product into pname but there is no product field in Order Model.

Comment: From the Order model you have shown,clearly there is a product field pname = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)  ..It is a foreign key field

Comment: Should I write this filter query in new_order function or NewOrder function

Comment: Write it in the same function where you want to create the Order @AbhishekKumar

Comment: And I want to ask you that I want all the Product name(pname) from Product table in drop down list in Order form.html file and after select any one of them their respective category and brand name filled in respective input filed. For this what should be the query. @Mohit Harshan

Comment: if you want all product names,do query Product.objects.all().only('pname')...Return this as a context variable to template and you can populate the dropdown....POst asnother question about this and i can help @AbhishekKumar

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53627349/how-to-filter-all-details-of-a-particular-field-from-one-model-and-populate-it-i?noredirect=1#comment94117302_53627349

Comment: Please see the above link where I put my questions @Mohit Harshan

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the pname in the Order table is a foreign key to the product table. You cannot assign values to a foreign key column, instead, you should assign the product object.

Do something like this.

```
pn=Product.objects.get(pname='nokia')
Order.objects.create(pname=pn,.....)
```